# isolating a div by class name in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a plugin called [jquery upload preview](http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/) to upload an image and preview the image on the div as its background.

In my web page, I am dynamically creating more and more divs with the same class name but since the class names are all the same, the upload preview is getting applied for all. I want every other div to get isolated/differentiated from each other.

Is there any solution I can apply here?  Please check out [this link](https://codepen.io/abh19021/pen/bvMGYN?editors=1010), it's a pen where I have isolated the issue.

The plugin uses  $.uploadPreview (for your quick reference) and the field is called preview_box : '.imgCard',

Thank you so much, guys.

Below is the code in HTML and JS.

**HTML**

```
<section id="alterationForm1">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="imgPreview" class="text-center">
            <div class="imgCard">
                <input type="file" name="front_image" id="front-image-upload" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Dropdown List-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><p class="dropDownLabel">Select alteration type</p></label>
            <select class="form-control alterationTypeSelect" name="alterationTypeSelect">
                <option value="button">Button</option>
                <option value="stitching">Stitching</option>
                <option value="cloth">Cloth</option>
                <option value="fabrics">Fabrics</option>
                <option value="otherClick">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="hideMe textBoxDiv">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Additional alteration details</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--text box div-->
        <div class="submitButton text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-pill">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <!--submitButton-->
    </div>
    <!--card-->
</section>
<!--alteration form-->
<div class="demoClass">
    <div class="card" data-duplicate="demo">
        <div class="imgCard" value="imageArea">
            <input type="file" name="front_image" id="front-image-upload" />
        </div>
        <!--Dropdown List-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><p class="dropDownLabel">Select alteration type</p></label>
            <select class="form-control alterationTypeSelect" name="alterationTypeSelect">
                <option value="button">Button</option>
                <option value="stitching">Stitching</option>
                <option value="cloth">Cloth</option>
                <option value="fabrics">Fabrics</option>
                <option value="otherClick">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="hideMe textBoxDiv">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Additional alteration details</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--text box div-->
        <div class="submitButton text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-pill">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <!--submitButton-->
    </div>
    <!--card-->
    <div id="addOnButton" class="text-center">
         <button class="btn-danger btn-sm" data-duplicate-add="demo">Add More</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!--demo class-->
```

**Jquery PART**

```
//question mark tooltip
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

//uploading image
$.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#front-image-upload",   // Default: .image-upload
    preview_box:  ".imgCard",    // Default: .image-label
    label_default: "Choose File",   // Default: Choose File
    label_selected: "Change File",  // Default: Change File
    no_label: false                 // Default: false
});
$('body').on('change', '.alterationTypeSelect', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === 'otherClick') {

        $(this).parent().parent().find('.textBoxDiv').removeClass('hideMe');
    } else {

        $(this).parent().parent().find('.textBoxDiv').addClass('hideMe');
    }   
});
//Dynamic Adding
$("#czContainer").czMore();
```

Any help is appreciated, please. Thank you so much.

Anything by which I can isolate div with class .imgCard from other .imgCard divs which are dynamically created.

EDIT : The function which generates the div is " $("#czContainer").czMore(); " which is powered by another plugin called [jquery duplicate](https://github.com/ReallyGood/jQuery.duplicate). The function is mentioned at the end of the jquery code.

Comment: What's the function the generates the divs?

Comment: The function which generates the div is  " $("#czContainer").czMore();
" which is powered by another plugin called jquery duplicate.  The function is mentioned at the end of the jquery code.

Comment: ok, and what's the class name of those divs which it generates?

Comment: the class name is called '.imgCard'.

and I  hope, my question is understandable as I have mentioned the class name in there. Please let me know.

Comment: Checkout my answer. Add the code I've added at the end of your JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [plugin](https://github.com/opoloo/jquery_upload_preview/blob/master/assets/js/jquery.uploadPreview.js) does not have much customization.

IDs are unique -- so you shouldn't have multiple `#front-image-upload`. Use class instead e.g. `.front-image-upload`

```
<div class="imgCard">
    <input type="file" name="front_image" class="front-image-upload" />
</div>
```

Use `$.uploadPreview()` in a loop with [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
function bindUploadPreview() {
    $('.imgCard').each(function (i) {
        var inputField = ".front-image-upload:eq(" + i + ")",
            previewBox = ".imgCard:eq(" + i + ")";
        // unbind onchange
        $(inputField).unbind();
        // bind onchange
        $.uploadPreview({
            input_field: inputField,
            preview_box: previewBox,
            label_default: "Choose File",
            label_selected: "Change File",
            no_label: false
        });
    });
}
```

In terms of the dynamically created cards, you can listen to the [duplicate.add](https://github.com/ReallyGood/jQuery.duplicate/blob/master/jquery.duplicate.js#L37) event handler. Then call the function above again. Note, the use of `unbind` to remove the `onchange` event.

```
$('body').on('duplicate.add', bindUploadPreview);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEqwPJ)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much, Mike. I wonder how long will it take me to become comfortable with JS like you.
This definitely helps. I am trying to break down your code and doing my best to understand it in depth. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot clone divs with an id without altering that id, since in html the `id` has to be unique.

What you need to do is you have to manipulate the newly added row and change the `id="front-image-upload"` to `id="front-image-upload-2"` and `class="imgCard"` to `class="imgCard-2"` (or create a new class if you are going to loose some styling if you replace imgCard with imgCard-2) for the second cloned row and so on. You can do this by using a callback function on `onAdd` of `czMore` as follows:

```
$("#czContainer").czMore({
    onAdd: function(){

        //Manipulate the id of the new cloned row here and also set the preview upload for the new id

        $.uploadPreview({
            input_field: "#front-image-upload-2",   // Default: .image-upload
            preview_box:  ".imgCard-2",    // Default: .image-label
            label_default: "Choose File",   // Default: Choose File
            label_selected: "Change File",  // Default: Change File
            no_label: false                 // Default: false
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this helps. But you need to generate new class and id targets for the new cloned rows in order to avoid the uploadPreview to target elements with same classes or ids

Comment: Thanks for your response. let me also use this solution and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch all the elements by the class them, iterate through them and then add a unique class to each of them.

try to add this to your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

   let myImages = $('.imgCard');

   for (let i=0; i < k.length; i++) {
      myImages.classList.add('myImage' + i);
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to include it in my code. I need a little time as I am new to jquery. Let you know.

Comment: Put it at the end of your code. It will give each of the `.imgCard` divs a new unique class name. now you can fetch each of them by its new class name. just remember to stay in `$(document).ready` scope

Comment: but I have tried putting it into my code but it still isn't working. I made sure that it stays within the scope. I also did put it at the end of the code.

Comment: I still cannot individually add new images to the dynamically generated div.

Answer (score 0):

I think the jquery plugin you are using id for a single input field in a page, thus for multiple inputs, you have to assign `$.uploadPreview` differently but here you also have dynamically added content so it is difficult to manage all elements with this method, 
So instead of using this plugin you can use this code:

```js
//question mark tooltip
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(input).parents('.imgCard').css('background', 'url('+ e.target.result +') center center no-repeat');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $('body').on('change', '#front-image-upload', function() {
        readURL(this);
    });

//Dynamically adding when clicked on the "Add more" button
$('body').on('change', '.alterationTypeSelect', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === 'otherClick') {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.textBoxDiv').removeClass('hideMe');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.textBoxDiv').addClass('hideMe');
    }   
});

//Dynamic Adding
$("#czContainer").czMore();
```

```css
/*gobal*/
body,
html{
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#alteration{
    padding: 1rem 0 0;
}
.hideMe{
    display: none;
}
.hideMe2{
    display: none;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#addOnButton .btn-danger{
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
/*Alteration Section*/
/*spans*/
.imgCard i, .imgCard2 i{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
/*Cards*/
.card{
    padding: .5rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown-el {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #444;
  outline: none;
  border: .06em solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #cde4f5;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el input {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-el label {
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s color ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el label:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
}
.dropdown-el input:checked + label {
  display: block;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.dropdown-el input:checked + label:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-el::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.8em;
  top: 0.9em;
  border: 0.3em solid #3694d7;
  border-color: #3694d7 transparent transparent transparent;
  transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el.expanded {
  border: 0.06em solid #3694d7;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .25em;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 3px 5px 0px;
  max-height: 15em;
}
.dropdown-el.expanded label {
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
}
.dropdown-el.expanded label:hover {
  color: #3694d7;
}
.dropdown-el.expanded input:checked + label {
  color: #3694d7;
}
.dropdown-el.expanded::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  top: .55em;
}
/*Dropdown el2*/
.dropdown-el2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #444;
  outline: none;
  border: .06em solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #cde4f5;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el2 input {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-el2 label {
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s color ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el2 label:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
}
.dropdown-el2 input:checked + label {
  display: block;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.dropdown-el2 input:checked + label:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-el2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.8em;
  top: 0.9em;
  border: 0.3em solid #3694d7;
  border-color: #3694d7 transparent transparent transparent;
  transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-el2.expanded2 {
  border: 0.06em solid #3694d7;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .25em;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 3px 5px 0px;
  max-height: 15em;
}
.dropdown-el2.expanded2 label {
  border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
}
.dropdown-el2.expanded2 label:hover {
  color: #3694d7;
}
.dropdown-el2.expanded2 input:checked + label {
  color: #3694d7;
}
.dropdown-el2.expanded2::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  top: .55em;
}
.imgCard{
    background: url(http://abhisheksuresh.online/alter/assets/uploadImage.svg)center center no-repeat;
    height: 128px;
/*    width: 128px;*/
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgCard input {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/*
.imgCard label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://abhisheksuresh.online/alter/css/shards.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://abhisheksuresh.online/alter/js/shards.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://abhisheksuresh.online/alter/js/jquery.duplicate.min.js"></script>

<script
src="http://abhisheksuresh.online/alter2/js/jquery.uploadPreview.min.js"></script>




<section id="alterationForm1">
  <div class="card">
     <div class="imgPreview" class="text-center">
      <div class="imgCard">
       <input type="file" name="front_image" id="front-image-upload" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--Dropdown List-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><p class="dropDownLabel">Select alteration type</p></label>
      <select class="form-control alterationTypeSelect" name="alterationTypeSelect">
                      <option value="button">Button</option>
                      <option value="stitching">Stitching</option>
                      <option value="cloth">Cloth</option>
                      <option value="fabrics">Fabrics</option>
                      <option value="otherClick">Other</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="hideMe textBoxDiv">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Additional alteration details</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--text box div-->
    <div class="submitButton text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-pill">Submit</a>
    </div>
    <!--submitButton-->
  </div>
  <!--card-->
</section>
<!--alteration form-->
<div class="demoClass">
  <div class="card" data-duplicate="demo">
    <div class="imgCard" value="imageArea">
       <input type="file" name="front_image" id="front-image-upload" />
    </div>
    <!--Dropdown List-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><p class="dropDownLabel">Select alteration type</p></label>
      <select class="form-control alterationTypeSelect" name="alterationTypeSelect">
                      <option value="button">Button</option>
                      <option value="stitching">Stitching</option>
                      <option value="cloth">Cloth</option>
                      <option value="fabrics">Fabrics</option>
                      <option value="otherClick">Other</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="hideMe textBoxDiv">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Additional alteration details</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--text box div-->
    <div class="submitButton text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-pill">Submit</a>
    </div>
    <!--submitButton-->
  </div>
  <!--card-->
  <div id="addOnButton" class="text-center">
    <button class="btn-danger btn-sm" data-duplicate-add="demo">Add More</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--demo class-->
```